# Zenmap only shows the router

Tags: networking, router, nmap

Zenmap (GUI of nmap) is only showing the router and not showing any other device on the network, even that i am certain that there are other devices that is the code i entered `nmap -T4 -F 192.168.1.1/51`
and this is the output:
`Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-18 19:01 EDT
Illegal netmask in "192.168.1.1/51". Assuming /32 (one host)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.0065s latency).
Not shown: 96 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
23/tcp  open  telnet
53/tcp  open  domain
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
MAC Address: 58:BA:D4:A4:D7:4F (Huawei Technologies)`

I am new to kali, and i am getting used to it. My kernal version :5.6.0-kali1-amd64
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "/24" for a class-c private address. Unless you are using a custom subnet range /24 (255.255.255.0) for the subnet-mask is correct.

Comment: Thank you, sorry if it was so obvious, but i have an additional question why 24 specifically ?

Comment: Ah, the "/24" is just another notation of representing the subnet mask. Check out **Cisco learning** for ipv4 subnetting. Or just Google for tutorials. Get ready for lessons in binary! Note that the subnet mask is what's sets the border between network number, and host portions of any network.